# A is a 2*2 matrix with real entries and non-zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a $2×2$ matrix with real entries and $A≠0$, $A^2=0$.
I need to find the rank, kernel and nullity of $A$, so first I know $\ker A=A$ hence Im $A⊂A$. However, I am not sure how to continue.
The second part is prove that Im $A=\ker A$, but I know once I find out rank and kernel, it's not hard to prove.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{ker} A = A$? $A$ is a matrix (or operator) and its kernel is a set of vectors....

Answer (score 1):

Because $A^2=0$, we know that $\det A=0$, and because $A\neq0$, we obtain that $A=\left(\matrix{v\\a.v}\right)$, where $v\in\mathbb {R^2}$.

Do you know how finish?

Answer (score 0):

Using Sylvester's inequality, it can be shown that $2\dim\ker A \leq n$. Then $\dim\ker A = 1$.

To show that $\operatorname{im} A = \ker A$, observe that $A \circ A(x) = 0$ for all $x$, hence $A(y) = 0$ for all $y \in \operatorname{im} A$, and $\operatorname{im} A \subseteq \ker A$. The reverse is established easily.